# How long does it take for Google YouTube Data API quota limit increase to review request?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I just want to know how long it takes for Google YouTube Data API to review a request for quota increase. I only got an email saying my request was submitted, but I have no idea when it'll respond back. I have emailed requests to google before and was never heard back. I am anxious to know if my request will be approved or looked at.

Comment: Maybe the best you can do is to seek help from the [YouTube Help Center](https://support.google.com/youtube#topic=7505892). Also there are some [forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube) and [help channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTubeHelp) in which I think is monitored by YouTube. Try to visit, maybe you can find the answer there.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I just did, but I looked on Stackoverflow and the last time google engineers answered questions on Stackoverflow was in February 2018, so they have stopped support 3 months ago. Really disappointed that they basically lied when they said google engineers would be able to help answer questions, our requests are left untouched, there are broken forms that no longer work, and there is no support at all. I'm just really disappointed in Google's google developer support, it's non existent. I'm going to think about using youtube api and maybe switching to twitch streaming instead.